# Click a Web Page Button with VBA

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

I'm trying to click the "Show Overnight" button at the bottom of the web page shown in the code below

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With IE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "http://tvlistings.zap2it.com/tv/movies-on-tv?aid=zap2it&tod=rightNow&vn=sm"
    .Top = 50
    .Left = 530
    .Height = 400
    .Width = 400

Do Until Not IE.Busy And IE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop

End With
```

I've tried the following code to click the button without success

```
IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("zc-item-button").Item(1).Click

IE.Document.GetElementsByClassName("zc-item-button").Item(1).FireEvent ("click()")
```

I think the relevant source code is:

```
<div class="zc-item-button">
    <a href="" onclick="$('#overnight-bucket').show();$('#overnight-bucket').find('.open').each(function(){writeShows($(this));});$(this).hide();return false;" class="">Show Overnight</a>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help, I appreciate it...Ron

Comment: How many `zc-item-button`s are there? Should you be referencing `Item(0)`?

Comment: There are 3 (0, 1 and 2), button "1" is the one I'm interested in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getelementsbyclassname only gets the div elements, which have no click handler.  You need the click the first child element instead. You can use getelementsbytagname("a") on your div to get a handle on the link.

Answer (score 1):

Or use a [CSS selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) of:

```
a[onclick*='#overnight-bucket']
```

This says element(s) with an `a` tag, that have an attribute `onlick`, which *contains* the string `'#overnight-bucket'`.

---

**CSS query:**

[image: CSS query]

---

**VBA:**

You apply a CSS selector using the [`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) method of `document`.

```
.document.querySelector("a[onclick*='#overnight-bucket']").Click
```